# Iterator over pure virtual container interface in C++

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator, containers

I have a pure virtual interface to a container which is more or less like this:

```
class IContainer
{
public:
    virtual ~IContainer() = default;
    virtual Element& operator[](size_t index) = 0;
    virtual const Element& operator[](size_t index) const = 0;
    virtual size_t size() const = 0;
};
```

I would like to make use of range for loops, so I need to define begin() and end(). In order to do so, I need to define the iterator type as well.

It should be not be particularly hard, but nevertheless I would like to know if is there already anything in STL or Boost that can come to help, before I start coding something that already exists.

Comment: Might be what you are after: [std::iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator).

Comment: @Aconcagua but that's deprecated...

Comment: [boost::iterator_facade](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html). I am afraid that you have to the implement the type erasure part yourself.

Comment: Literal offtopic as asking to recommend a third-party library (Boost)

Comment: @SergeyA The question appears to be (partially) about the functionality of boost. Why would OP ask us to recommend a library they are already well aware of?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I see boost as a collection of libraries, and to me, OP is asking to recommend a particular library within this collection.

Comment: @SergeyA it's not "recommend a library" but "know if this library contains something with $semantic (or a close match)"

Comment: @SergeyA That argument might apply to "Which library in boost includes foo?" (although I would disagree), but that's not the question at hand. However, the question is "How do I solve X?", and the fact that using boost for that is acceptable does not turn the practical question into recommendation question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen OP is literally asking for a library in boost. `...I would like to know if is there already anything in STL or Boost that can come to help...`

Comment: @SergeyA Again, I read this as "How can I solve this problem using standard C++ and boost?", which, given how widely used boost is, seems like a reasonable thing to ask. But even *if* you insist that asking how to do something with boost is asking for a library (which seems dubious, as "Use boost.container." hardly would answer this question), how would that fit with the spirit of the rule that is clearly outlined in the UI? How would this "attract opinionated answers or spam"?

Comment: @SergeyA given that the question says "STL or Boost" would you mark every question off topic that says "how can I do X using the STL"?

Comment: @BaummitAugen, difference of opinions makes markets, as they say. I still hold mine.

Comment: Unrelated to the library discussion: it is not clear to me why every container type must support `operator[]` to begin with. That certainly does not hold for the standard containers, see e.g. `std::set`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen it could be that OP doesn't realise there is a distinction between the shared members of *SequenceContainer*s, *AssociativeContainer*s and *UnorderedAssociativeContainer*s (probably because .Net has `IContainer` that maps to *SequenceContainer*)

Answer (score 3):

It might not be a good idea, but adding `for(:)` loop support is relatively easy here.  I'll be minimal.

I'll create an `iteroid`, a not-iterator that is enough to support `for(:)` loops.  This requires `++`, `!=` and unary `*` support, and nothing else.

```
template<class C>
struct index_iteroid {
  decltype(auto) operator*()const {
    return (*container)[i];
  }
  index_iteroid(index_iteroid const&)=default;
  index_iteroid& operator=(index_iteroid const&)=default;
  friend bool operator==(index_iteroid const& lhs, index_iteroid const& rhs) {
    return std::tie(lhs.i, lhs.container)==std::tie(rhs.i, rhs.container);
  }
  friend bool operator!=(index_iteroid const& lhs, index_iteroid const& rhs) {
    return !(lhs==rhs);
  }
  void operator++()&{
    ++i;
  }
  index_iteroid(C* c, std::size_t in):i(in), container(c) {}
private:
  std::size_t i = 0;
  C* container = nullptr;
};
```

now we use it:

```
class IContainer
{
public:
    virtual ~IContainer() = default;
    virtual Element& operator[](size_t index) = 0;
    virtual const Element& operator[](size_t index) const = 0;
    virtual size_t size() const = 0;
    index_iteroid<IContainer> begin() { return {this, 0}; }
    index_iteroid<IContainer> end() { return {this, size()}; }
    index_iteroid<IContainer const> begin() const { return {this, 0}; }
    index_iteroid<IContainer const> end() const { return {this, size()}; }
};
```

and there you have it.

```
void test( IContainer* cont ) {
  if (!cont) return;
  for(Element& e : *cont) {
    // code
  }
}
```

please excuse any typos.

Now a full iterator takes about 2-3 times as much code as my `iteroid` does, but nothing tricky, just annoying boilerplate mostly.

---

The standard doesn't have much to help you.  For boost, you could compose a counting iterator with a function caling iterator/generator, and have the function call use `[]`.  Boost also has some utilities to make it take less boilerplate to write a full iterator, if you want to upgrade the iteroid to an iterator.

Comment: I ended up by making MyIterator inherit from boost::counting_iterator< size_t >, keeping a reference to typename ContainerType and redirecting operator* to base class operator* using the result on the container operator[] and returning the accessed element.

Comment: @nyar keep a pointer not reference: don't mix value and reference semantics.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't do "interfaces" like this. The idiomatic way is for the (potential) clients of `IContainer` to instead be templated over the container type and just call `values[index]`, or be templated over an iterator type and call like `*(first + offset)`.

In C++20 you will be able to write a `Container` [*Concept*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts), which behaves somewhat like an interface definition, but you can already express a Concept as documented requirements.

If instead you want a type-erased random access "container", you can use [`boost::any_range<Element, boost::random_access_traversal_tag>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html)

Comment: Not sure what "C++ doesn't do" should mean. If you mean that template only libraries such as STL and Boost do not do this, than sure, they do not.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 I mean that the *standard* describe a number of interfaces as semantic requirements on (groups of) expressions involving type parameters. And when it does type-erasure, it generally doesn't require the *user* to inherit from a particular class.